# Spheres as Homogeneous Spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homogeneous-spaces

Any odd dimensional sphere $S^{2n+1}$ can be expressed as an homogenous space of $SU(n+1)$ by $S^{2n+1} \simeq SU(n+1)/SU(n)$. Any even dimensional sphere $S^{2n}$ sphere can be expressed as an homogeneous space of $SO(n)$ according to $S^{2n} \simeq SO(n)/SO(n-1)$. Can we make for a switch here? In explicit, can one realize the odd spheres as $SO(n)$ homogeneous spaces, and can one realize the even spheres as $SU(n)$ homogeneous spaces.

Comment: Are you sure about your statement $S^{2n}=Sp(n)/Sp(n-1)$ ? What is the proof ?

Comment: I meant to write SO(n) not Sp, it is hopefully ok now.

Comment: Yes, now it is not a duplicate. You still have $Sp(n)$ in the text, though.

Comment: For $Sp(n)$ see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651906/spheres-as-symplectic-homogeneous-spaces).

Comment: Fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of the question has a positive answer, since we have
$$
S^n\cong SO(n+1)/SO(n)
$$
also for odd $n$. For the case $SU(n)$ this is not possible in this way, however it might be realized in a different way, e.g.,
$$
S^6\cong G_2/SU(3),
$$
where $n=6$ is even.

Comment: The last identity is nice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And $S^2=CP^1(\mathbb C)$ is also $SU(2)/ U(1)$